# Connect Asus vivo rt to laptop

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, tablet

How can I connect an Asus Vivo RT to a laptop to test win 8 applications? When I plug in the wire nothing shows up for some reason :/

Or is there a way in which I can deploy an app onto the tablet to test it? I have so far installed the visual studio remote tools on the tablet but how can I transfer an application to test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install a remote debugger on your RT device and connect to it (just need to be on the same wifi network).

The info you need is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsvc/archive/2012/10/26/windows-rt-windows-store-app-debugging.aspx

Comment: This link gives more detailed information, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441469.aspx

Comment: Thank you! I also used this page which helped me a lot! http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/mihail_mateev/archive/2012/12/05/how-to-start-with-debugging-deploying-windows-store-apps-to-arm-tablet.aspx